# AWS Organization - Does joined account mean it is automatically linked to the payer account?

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-organizations

Asking for advise again with regards to AWS Organization.

If I joined a new account to my organization, does it mean that is already linked to the payer account? Or I have to do something else to linked it to the payer account?

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 2):

When an AWS account joins an AWS Organization, it gets automatically linked and the payer account is responsible for paying for all usage, data, and resources used by the new member account.

You can find more information in the billing section of the [AWS Organization FAQs](https://aws.amazon.com/organizations/faqs/).

Comment: You’re welcome. Please don’t forget to accept the answer if it was helpful. Either mine or the one by Mary’s Dubrava, as both are correct.

Answer (score 1):

No you don't need to do anything else. Master account is always responsible for all the billing.